# Derivative of block matrix

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{R}}\bigg(\mathbf{R}\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{3}\mathbf{R}\bigg)$$
where $\mathbf{R}$ is a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}_3$ is a Pauli matrix, is the answer

$$\mathbf{R}\boldsymbol{\sigma}_3+\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{3}\mathbf{R}$$

by application of the product rule?

Comment: have you tried to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial R_{11}} \big(...\big)$ (by writing the expressions explicitly)?

Comment: this matrix $\mathbf{R}$ is arbitrary...not sure how I could

Comment: Note quite sure how you get the above form. Is there a $\operatorname{tr}$ missing perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(R)= R\sigma_3R$ and then $f(R+H)-f(R) = R\sigma_3H+H\sigma_3R +O(\|H\|^2)$. Hence
$Df(R)H = R\sigma_3H+H\sigma_3R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is $H$?

Comment: Generally the derivative of $f:A \to B$ is a linear operator $Df(x):A \to B$. We tend to conflate the derivative operator with the number (or matrix as appropriate) used to represent the derivative. Not all derivative operators can be written in the form $A \cdot h$, the above being one example.

Answer (score 1):

In index notation,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial R_{ab}} ( R_{ik} (\sigma_3)_{kl} R_{lj} ) = \delta_{ai} \delta_{bk} (\sigma_3)_{kl} R_{lj} + R_{ik} (\sigma_{3})_{kl} \delta_{al} \delta_{bj} \\
= \delta_{ai} (\sigma_3)_{bl} R_{lj} + R_{ik} (\sigma_{3})_{kl} \delta_{bj} . $$
In particular, the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix can't be a matrix, since you have two indices from the differentiated matrix and two from the differentiating matrix. This is reflected in the free indices above.

(To convince yourself of this, note that the derivative of a vector with respect to a vector is $\partial v_{i}/\partial u_j$, which has two free indices and so is a matrix: this is particularly clear for $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}$, for example.)